# How to catch asp.net textbox1.text via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

net textbox control. so I try to catch via jquery. but I cant. How can I do this. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just name your textbox control, say `tbName`. Then, using jQuery, do this:

```
$("#tbName").val();
```

Comment: yes, I found that your answer is good. I try two page. one of them is wordked but other isnt worked. I think that the problem is about other things..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I advise you to use class instead of id to select the control. Asp.net IDs change at runtime. You need to do the following jquery command:
$('.textbox').val()

Comment: I don't think that's right. The name you give the control in ASP.net translates to the element's ID in HTML.